# how to list fonts installed from Chrome packaged app

Tags: fonts, typeerror, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to use chrome.fontSettings API to get the list of fonts installed on a computer.But I got a message **'fontSettings' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, and this is a packaged app.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you created a "new version" chrome app. Check [this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps.html).

> Warning: All content in this doc refers to the legacy version of packaged apps. Your legacy packaged apps will still work, but you won't have access to any of the new APIs. Check out the new version of Chrome Apps; otherwise, you're missing out!

As the message says, 'fontSettings' is only allowed for legacy apps, not new version apps. Check APIs for new version [here](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index.html), good luck finding an alternative.